# ios touchesBegan not called on arm64 devices

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a custom UIView based on this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/uiview-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-in-ios-5-a-5-star-rating-view

On arm64 devices (iphone 5s, 6, 6 plus, ipad air): UIView's touchesBegan method never gets called. On earlier versions (iphone 5, 4s,...) it works like expected - touchesBegan gets called. tested on simulators (iOS 7.1, 8.1) and ipad air (iOS 8.1).

It is strange that sample project from the tutorial is working...

Any suggestions except go through the tutorial for the 10th time again?

Comment: Post some code, or use the interface inspector while debugging to make sure your view hierarchy can accept touches. It's hard to say what's wrong from your description of the issue.

Comment: @adis My view is accepting touches on older devices... Anyway I solved it with a trick. I wanted get touches working on my custom buttons ordered in grid 9x9. So I used UITapGestureRecognizer on background of my buttons and in touch callback I just checked on which button am I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My view is accepting touches on older devices... Anyway I solved it with a trick. I wanted get touches working on my custom buttons ordered in grid 9x9. So I used UITapGestureRecognizer on background of my buttons and in touch callback I just checked on which button am I.